# Samsung Galaxy Tab produces jerky animations at the start of the game

Tags: android

First to thank you all for your great help, I have finally published my game puzzle, both full and free version. Not sure how would I do it without Stackoverflow.
I also learned a lot by helping others.

The issue I am having is that when I start applications I have developed, on Samsung Galaxy Tab, animations are jerky at first 10 seconds or so, then they become smooth. This is not the case on HTC desire or Samsung Europe mobile.

It does not matter whether the animation is a frame by frame canvas drawing or built in android view animations.

I wonder if there is something I can do to prevent this slow down; is it something to do the way Galaxy Tab buffers when loading an application and optimising the resources? Or is this to do with the fact that it has a higher resolution screen… or both.

One way to deal with this could be to create some kind of animated intro in the same activity which would preload/optimise Galaxy Tab for the game.

*EDIT after few months of development:*

**When testing an app on Galaxy Tab it starts slow and the animation is jerky, but if I  restart the app and/or unplug the USB link, then it run fast as it should.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing any of you're code. I couldn't say if it's a general problem with your code that only becomes apparent on slower devices, or if it is actually an issue with the Tab.

When testing my applications on the Galaxy Tab the general user interface is slower than on a Galaxy S (2.2), Nexus S or HTC Hero (2.1) but there are reasons for this:

- Nexus S has a better GPU and Android version
- Samsung have enabled some hardware-acceleration wizardry in their later Galaxy S builds
- The resolution of the Galaxy Tab is higher

My main experience has been that the effect of the garbage collector (GC) is much more prominent on the Tab, therefore it could be something to do with your memory management -- are you creating objects in your `onDraw` method?

Comment: Actually, yes, I am creating three int local varibales 60 times per second. I guess that means they have to be destroyed 60 times per second as well...

Comment: I would hope that they'd just be created on the stack and not cost anything.  I could be wrong though.  But I generally agree with Joseph that your problem is possibly GC-related, although it might be related to initialization, swapping-in, and so on.  My experience has been that all apps are slow at first, until the system is done unpacking the jar and swapping everything in.

Comment: Thank you both for valuable comments.